# How to add jquery rollover effect

Tags: jquery, css, toggle

I have a toggle button and it works perfectly but now I want to see if there is a way to get a hover effect in addition to the toggle effect.

I checked out some tutorials on google but nothing showed me how to add onto the current configuration.

You can view the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/TC5kn/

I didn't know how to input images into the fiddle but I was trying to show that when the green portion is clicked the arrow changes direction from down to up.

In addition to the arrow changing direction I wanted to change the hover color.

It was very late when I asked this and obviously it was a simple fix.  The answer given is correct.

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you just do the hover effect in CSS?

```
.content:hover {background:red}
```

Comment: And if you're using a background image here, use sprites: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/ Then you just change the background offset for the hover pseudo-class/selector